# How to get conclusive evidence about if a MacBook Pro video or logic board is malfunctioning?

Tags: mac, macbook

I have an early 2008 MacBook Pro, but I'm starting to watch unfortunate symptoms like some random and unexplained flickering.

Reading this [link](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2377) I'm almost sure that I need to go to an Apple Authorized Service Provider. To be certain about the condition of my MBP I need to perform exhaustive testing.

Any guide for stress testing the video and logic board, and to get conclusive results about the state of my MBP?

I'm very comfortable with computers and complicated stuff won't scare me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Apple rather underplayed it there - the error is in the manufacturing and simply, it is a matter of when and not if... so, if you have one of those models, it is likely to fail.

If you are seeing flickering, most likely it is affecting you right now.

the only way to really test it is just to play high definition video, games, rendering or anything that can max out your video card for a period of time - however as the problem is heat related, doing this **will** make it even worse, possibly to the point where it will not boot or be usable.

I would just go for a repair now if it is free.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost as you are trying to pretty much kill your computer on purpose make sure that you back up whatever you cannot afford to lose. Yes, you are hoping to only kill the Video Card, but you never know what can happen when a device connected to your motherboard dies.

Download a game demo from [Apple](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/games/demos_updates/) and make sure that it uses OpenGL. Start the game up and keep it running non-stop. Set all the settings to as high as they will go. Some games have demo modes where the computer simulates gameplay, that is probably your best bet.

Since your laptop is covered by Apple it will be fixed for free. Might as well kill the video card (or get it to a point where the problem is undeniable) so there is no question to if your claim is valid or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer came with an Apple Hardware Test DVD. Boot from it and run everything it has to offer.